# Check whether the job is completed or not through unix

Tags: bash, unix, spark-submit

I have to run multiple spark job one by one in a sequence, So I am writing a shell script. One way I can do is to check success file in output folder for job status, but i wanna know that is there any other way to check the status of spark-submit job using unix script, where I am running my jobs.

Comment: Is a submitted job a success when the job is running or when it is finished with exitcode 0?

Answer (score 0):

You can use command

```
yarn application -status <APPLICATIOM ID>
```

where `<APPLICATIOM ID>` is your application ID and check for line like:

```
State : RUNNING
```

This will give you the status of your application

To check the list of application, run via yarn you can use command

```
yarn application --list
```

You can add also -appTypes to limit the listing based on the application type

Comment: I have to use it in shell script so i dont have the job ID at that time